# git - commit definition from the "Git from bottom-up" booklet

Tags: git, commit, definition

I am reading ["Git from bottom-up"](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/) and it defines "commit" as follows:

*"A commit is a snapshot of your working tree at some point in time"*

However, I do not agree with that definition. You might have 5 files (1 new and 4 modified) in your working tree but only 3 added to the index. Therefore, if you commit, your commit will not correspond to the current working tree.

Is there something I am missing or am I correct?

Comment: What do you think the definition of "working tree" is?  Is a file that is not in the index "in" the working tree?

Comment: @GreenAsJade From the same book "A working tree is any directory on your filesystem which has a repository associated with it". That is a working tree for me. And yes, a file that is not in the index is inside the working tree for me.

Comment: Yes, but does the "working tree" (which you defined as a directory) include files that are not in the index?   Usually, people don't worry about this level of detail in definition ... ultimately, who cares?   The statement you quoted is intended as a high level explanation of what is going on, rather than a precise definition.  I think that's the important thing to understand: this statement is usually given in introductory sections to orient the newcomer, not as a statement of precise implementation detail.

Comment: @Tiago I remember being confused by that passage of GFTBU too. Let me gather my thoughts and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Jubobs Looking forward for your answer too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not missing something. It is certainly possible to have commits that don't represent a state your working tree was actually in at some point in time. But they do function as logically sort of snapshots of the state of the tree - even if it's a logical state which never existed on disk.